Detecting center and radius of craters in microscopy images
I want to find the center and the radius of crater-like features in microscopy images using Python.
I have images like this, they are numpy arrays representing the height map of a surface.

I need the center to create a radial profile later on in my processing.
So far I have tried to simply apply a height threshold, binarizing the image and only keeping the highest features, then fitting a circle or ellipse to these points.

My problem is, that some images cannot be thresholded very well. A lower and higher threshold both make the circle detection worse.
I tried using Canny, but I haven't had much success.
How can I properly detect these circles?
This is the code so far:
from skimage.measure import EllipseModel, CircleModel
from skimage.draw import ellipse_perimeter, circle_perimeter
import numpy as np
import diplib as dip
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path

base_path = Path("folder including multiple images")

glob = base_path.rglob("*_f.npz")

for file in glob:
    image_grey: np.ndarray = np.load(file)["arr_0"]

    max_peak = image_grey.max()
    min_peak = image_grey.min()

    # i adjust the value at the end here to set a certain threshold
    threshold = max_peak - (max_peak-min_peak)*0.3

    rim_binarized = image_grey>=threshold
    points = np.argwhere(rim_binarized)

    ell = EllipseModel()
    succ = ell.estimate(points)
    print(succ)
    ye, xe, a, b = (int(round(x)) for x in ell.params[:-1])
    ey, ex = ellipse_perimeter(ye,xe,a,b,ell.params[-1])

    circ = CircleModel()
    circ.estimate(points)
    yc, xc, r = (int(round(x)) for x in circ.params)
    cy, cx = circle_perimeter(yc,xc,r)

    fig2, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=1, figsize=(12, 4),
                                    sharex=False, sharey=False)

    ax1.set_title('Original picture')
    ax1.imshow(image_grey)
    ax1.plot(cx,cy, "r,")
    ax1.plot(ex,ey, "m,")

    ax2.set_title('Rim')
    ax2.imshow(rim_binarized, cmap="Greys")

    dipimg = dip.Image(image_grey)

    ax3.set_title("Ridge")
    rad = dip.RadialMean(dipimg, binSize=1, center=(ye,xe), maxRadius="inner radius")
    ax3.plot(rad, label="ellipse")
    rad = dip.RadialMean(dipimg, binSize=1, center=(yc,xc), maxRadius="inner radius")
    ax3.plot(rad, label="circle")

    plt.show()


It is a rather grainy rice pudding like image, but the circles do look pretty good. You might want to try histogram equalisation to adaptively enhance contrast before applying your threshold. Another idea would be to use horizontal and vertical edge detection to look for circle candidates first - it should find squares that way.

can you post that without the plot stuff around it? do not crop it out of the plot. post the image itself. -- also present "bad" examples, with the coffee stain not being there, being very faint, or not being nearly centered

You can download the files here: https://github.com/rk-exxec/ridge_evaluation/tree/main/numpy_files

@Raphael, I've updated my answer, I hope you will find it useful.

@MartinBrown Thank you for the suggestions. I tried histogram equalization in combination with the K-means clustering suggested by Good_Man. That seems to produce some workable results. the edges are too fuzzy to use edge detection I think.

I also added a RANSAC Circle fit, and this combination seems to work well so far.

Since you’re already using DIPlib, I would suggest you try RadonTransformCircles. By the way, dipimg = dip.Image(image_grey) is redundant, these functions accept any object that is like a NumPy array.

The following code should help you with the segmentation
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
 

 
# Read in the image
image = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\shorokhovi\Downloads\deGSv.png")
 
# Change color to RGB (from BGR)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
 
# Reshaping the image into a 2D array of pixels and 3 color values (RGB)
pixel_vals = image.reshape((-1,3))
 
# Convert to float type
pixel_vals = np.float32(pixel_vals)

#the below line of code defines the criteria for the algorithm to stop running, 
#which will happen is 100 iterations are run or the epsilon (which is the required accuracy) 
#becomes 85%
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 0.85)
 
# then perform k-means clustering with number of clusters defined as 3
#also random centres are initially choosed for k-means clustering
k = 2
retval, labels, centers = cv2.kmeans(pixel_vals, k, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
 
# convert data into 8-bit values
centers = np.uint8(centers)
segmented_data = centers[labels.flatten()]
 
# reshape data into the original image dimensions
segmented_image = segmented_data.reshape((image.shape))
 

gray = cv2.cvtColor(segmented_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert to grayscale
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
# Filter the image using filter2D, which has inputs: (grayscale image, bit-depth, kernel)

# The first parameter is the original image, 
# kernel is the matrix with which image is 
# convolved and third parameter is the number 
# of iterations, which will determine how much 
# you want to erode/dilate a given image. 
kernel = np.ones((7, 7), np.uint8) 
img_erosion = cv2.erode(blur, kernel, iterations=1) 
imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img_erosion, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgRGB,175,200, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
grey_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh) #Inverse

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(grey_inv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 175,200, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
contour_img = image.copy()
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
index = 1
isolated_count = 0
cluster_count = 0
for cntr in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
    convex_hull = cv2.convexHull(cntr)
    convex_hull_area = cv2.contourArea(convex_hull)
    ratio = area / convex_hull_area
    if ratio < 0.5:

        cv2.drawContours(contour_img, [cntr], 0, (0,0,255), 2)
        cluster_count = cluster_count + 1
    index = index + 1
    
plt.imshow(contour_img)
plt.show()

Output:

Original Image:


This looks very promising, I'll give it a shot!

Good luck! I've done image processing 9 years ago in Uni, so I would like to apologise for bad code structure, some of the steps might me redundant.

Thank you for the suggestion to use KMeans, it didn't solve my problem on its own but it certainly helped a lot!

I cobbled together a solution from all the suggestions, which seems to work pretty nicely.
First I apply histogram equalization, then do KMeans clustering and fit the Circle using a RANSAC algorithm. This works well for all my test cases so far.
Even for images with lots of debris and other non-circular structures.
There is probably some redundancy in the code.
from skimage.measure import  CircleModel
from skimage.exposure import equalize_adapthist
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
import diplib as dip

def _rim_from_image(image:np.ndarray, kmeans_n_clusters=50, threshold=0.5):
    image = equalize_adapthist(image)
    image_normalised = (image - image.min())/(image.max()-image.min())
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=kmeans_n_clusters, algorithm="lloyd").fit(image_normalised)
    labels = kmeans.labels_
    centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
    segmented_image = centers[labels]
    segmented_normalized = (segmented_image - segmented_image.min())/(segmented_image.max()-segmented_image.min())
    rim_binarized = segmented_normalized>=threshold
    # rim_binarized = image_normalised>=threshold
    points = np.argwhere(rim_binarized)
    return points, rim_binarized

def _ransac_circle(points:np.ndarray, n_samples:int=3, n_iterations:int=1000, threshold:float=0.1) -> tuple[CircleModel, np.ndarray]:
    from skimage.measure import CircleModel, ransac
    model, inliers = ransac(points, CircleModel, min_samples=n_samples, max_trials=n_iterations, residual_threshold=threshold)
    return model, inliers   

def _estimate_center(points:np.ndarray):
    circ, _ = _ransac_circle(points)
    yc, xc, r = (int(round(x)) for x in circ.params)
    residuals = np.sum(circ.residuals(points)**2)
    mean = np.mean(points, axis=0)
    # calculate total sum of squares
    diffs = points - mean
    tss = np.sum((diffs[:,0]+diffs[:,1])**2)

    # calculate r2 score
    r2 = 1-residuals/tss
    return yc, xc, r, r2   

def _radial_profile(image:np.ndarray, center:tuple, pixelscale:float, max_radius:str="inner radius"):
    dipimg = dip.Image(image)
    rad = dip.RadialMean(dipimg, binSize=1, center=center, maxRadius=max_radius)
    prof = np.asarray(rad)
    x_ax = np.arange(len(prof))
    # pixelscale = 0.040639999999999996e-6
    x_ax = x_ax * pixelscale
    return np.vstack((x_ax,prof)) 

image_grey: np.ndarray = np.load(file)["arr_0"]
points, rim = _rim_from_image(image_grey, kmeans_n_clusters=50, threshold=0.3)

yc, xc, r, r2 = _estimate_center(points)

radial_profile = _radial_profile(image_grey, (yc,xc), 6.33e-7, max_radius="inner radius")



